# CSS Inheritance involving div

Tags: css, html, inheritance

I've been reading a lot about CSS inheritance but I haven't been able to find anything about this question, and I'm confused. Please consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.anc {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
.des {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="anc">
  <p class="des">
    One <!-- Blue background, red text. Clearly inheritance. -->
  </p>
</div>

<p class="anc">
  <div class="des">
    Two <!-- Why is nothing inherited here? -->
  </div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The "One" text is working as I'd expect. But I don't understand why the "Two" text doesn't have a blue background and red text as well.

Is there some special rule about inheritance for block elements as opposed to inline elements? Or something special just about div? What am I missing here? Do you have an online reference to a very thorough explanation of inheritance? Everything I've seen (and I've been looking a long time) just explains examples like "One", but doesn't address issues like "Two".

I know that there are many (better) ways to get the same visual effect I'm asking for here. But this example is about me trying to understand inheritance in general, not trying to get any particular effect on this HTML code.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `<div>` inside `<p>` tag is not valid HTML. If you check the rendered HTML, it probably looks something like this:

```
<p class="anc"></p>
<div class="dec">TWO</div>
<p></p>
```

The browser fixes the invalid nesting, but that breaks your CSS definition.

Comment: Ha, wow, I had no idea. Well that completely clears that up. I'm glad inheritance is simpler than I thought, though apparently there are a few HTML concepts I need to review... Thank you to you and the other responders.

Answer (score 5):

You can't nest block-level elements inside a `<p>` - the opening `<p>` ends up acting as a self-closing element and pushes the descendant div out of the `<p>` as a  succeeding sibling. The paragraph also creates an empty `<p>` *after* the div; the structure ends up looking like:

```
<p class="anc"> </p>
    <div class="des">Two</div>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `<p>` can only contain inline elements. It is invalid to put a `<div>` in a `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

You swapped `<div>` and `<p>` in the second case. Also your css specifies `.des`, whereas your class name in the HTML is `dec` See working [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/MA7Kj/).

```
<div class="anc">
  <p class="dec">
    One <!-- Blue background, red text. Clearly inheritance. -->
  </p>
</div>

<div class="anc">
  <p class="dec">
    Two <!-- Why is nothing inherited here? -->
  </p>
</div>

.anc {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

Also, there's no need for the `inherit` as the child will be rendered within the parent, whose style you set already.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I noticed that dec/des typo early on and must have fixed it while you were writing your answer. The div - p swap was intentional, though, but misguided as I now see.